# examples on how to parse string in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, substring

I have the following string that I need to parse/extract the '20000' out of it.

```
"where f_id = '20000' and (flag is true or flag is null)"
```

Any sugguestions on best way to do this?

Here's more code to help understand:

```
List<ReportDto> reportDtoList = new ArrayList<ReportDto>();
for (Report report : reportList) {
List<ReportDetailsDto> ReportDetailsDtoList = new ArrayList<ReportDetailsDto>();

ReportDto reportDto = new ReportDto();
reportDto.setReportId(report.getReportId());
reportDto.setReportName(report.getName());

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\s'[0-9]+'");
String whereClause = report.getWhereClause();
Matcher m = p.matcher(whereClause);
```

Confused of what to do after this?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please add more detail into it.

Comment: split would do the job

Comment: I basically need to get that number value and set it into my dto

Comment: str.replaceAll("\\D", "")

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex to extract a single nonegative integer from your `String`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Or if you want to preserve the single quotes :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("['0-9]+");
```

This will extract a pattern that includes `'='` and a single space after that. It will print a `String` containing the number without `'='` or the space. So if this matches you know there is a number after a `'='`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\s'[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group().substring(3));
}
```

**EDIT**
based on the code you added this is how it would look like

```
List<ReportDto> reportDtoList = new ArrayList<ReportDto>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\s'[0-9]+");
for (Report report : reportList) {
    List<ReportDetailsDto> ReportDetailsDtoList = new ArrayList<ReportDetailsDto>();

    ReportDto reportDto = new ReportDto();
    reportDto.setReportId(report.getReportId());
    reportDto.setReportName(report.getName());

    String whereClause = report.getWhereClause();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(whereClause);
    if (m.find()) {
        String foundThis = m.group().substring(3);
        // do something with foundThis
    } else {
        // didn't find a number or =
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i wrap it inside an if statment and then check if the string contains an "=" and then can I parse out the number from within the string?

if (a.getWhereClause().contains("="){
aDto.setFId(a.getWhereClause().....
}

This is where I'm a little confused

Comment: Thank you Manos - is there something I can add in here to exclude the single quotes returned in my string?

When I use your  example, the lastMatch for me is: 
'20000
'10000

etc...

Comment: Sorry I'm still a little confused. How would I get rid of the single quotes?

Comment: Hi, do you understand more with my code edit I added?

Comment: Thanks, just saw what you added!

Comment: When i take the String foundThis and then set it inside the reportDto, it is coming back as null>

    String foundThis = m.group().substring(3);
    reportDto.setFilterId(foundThis);

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: It should actually never be null, I tried printing it out and in the logs, it does print out but it still includes single quote at the end of the number.

20000'
20001'
etc..

But when I try to set it inside the dto, it is null

Comment: What if there was more than 1 filter id i need to extract in one string? And one of them is in single quotes, the other is by itself like this or around parenthesis. For example: 

where filter_5_id = 'xxxxx' and filter_12_id = xxxxxx

Comment: All these id's will be 5 or 6 digits in length as well

Comment: In StackOverflow the idea is you ask 1 question you get 1 maybe more answers to that question. There shouldn't be continuous modifications/expansions and new questions added to the original question and in the comments. Regular expressions is a big topic. You seem to want to handle multiple possibilities. I recommend you start from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and come back with new specific questions in StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); 
String s = "your string here";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
List<String> extracted = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) { 
   extracted.add(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for floats and negatives

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)(\\.\\d+)?"); 
        String s = "where f_id = '20000' 3.2 and (flag is true or flag is null)";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
        List<String> extracted = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) { 
           extracted.add(m.group());
        }

        for (String g : extracted)

            System.out.println(g);
```

prints out

```
20000
3.2
```

Comment: another question - once I get the string values, how would I set that as a variable and then be able to convert the string value to an integer so that I can set it into my DTO?

Comment: you can just use Integer.parseInt("2000")

Comment: so as per my code, the extracted List already has all of your numbers. just parse them one by one